# When using a GridView, SelectedIndex is always 0 when using custom select button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedindex, commandfield, datakey

When clicking the select button in gvSquid2, x gets a valid and correct value.  When clicking the select button in gvSquid, I get an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception because gv.`SelectedIndex`=0.  Additionally, gv.`SelectedDataKey` is null.  How do I get the `DataKey` information?  Putting it in a column is not acceptable, as it must be hidden from the user.  Hiding the column is useless, because during `DataBind()`, the value is discarded.  I ripped this example from Microsoft's website.  What am I missing?

```
<asp:gridview ID="gvSquid2" DataSourceID="dsComments" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvSquid_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="Username" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview> 

<asp:gridview ID="gvSquid" DataSourceID="dsComments" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvSquid_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Select" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectImageUrl="~/includes/RedX.jpg" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="Username" />
  </Columns>
</asp:gridview> 

protected void gvSquid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string x;
    x = gvSquid.DataKeys[gvSquid.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  `EnableViewState="true"` has to be set.  Once I changed that, suddenly the DataKeys appeared.

[This question helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276014/gridview-datakeys-collection-empty-when-gridview-is-in-an-edititemtemplate)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `SelectedRow` of the grid view to get to the `RowIndex`, like this:

```
protected void gvSquid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string x;
    GridViewRow theGridViewRow = gvSquid.SelectedRow;
    x = gvSquid.DataKeys[theGridViewRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `gvSquid.SelectedRow.RowIndex = 0`, so I'm still getting ArgumentOutOfRange Exception.  For that matter, `gvSquid.DataKeys.Count=0`, so it seems I'm losing everything DataKey related.